# DHCP server sending DHCPDISCOVERs

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp

After upgrading to Debian 8 running isc-dhcp-server I began seeing these on the logs:

```
servername dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (servername) via eth1
servername dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on xx.xx.xx.xx to yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (servername) via eth1
```

eth1 is and has always been configured with a static IP (different from the one beeing offered xx.xx.xx.xx), there isn't any dhclient process running and the "censored" MAC is eth1's.

Any ideas?

Comment: I presume it's checking it's not clashing with any other DHCP servers on the network.

Comment: I have about 20 similar servers and this is the only one doing this. Is there any option in dhcpd.conf to disable this?

Comment: You verified there's no _dhclient_ process, but there exist more DHCP clients than just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was indeed another dhcp client installed and running (dhcpcd5). The process was /sbin/dhcpcd.

Answer (score 0):

Since DHCP is a critical service, there are ways needed to make sure it can be configured HA. Checking for the existance of another DHCP server by sending a DISCOVER primitive is not an unusal ways to go there.

In fact it is just making less usual use of a very usual DHCP feature.

Comment: I have about 20 similar servers and this is the only one doing this. Is there any option in dhcpd.conf to disable this?